# For some reason my code adds 2 to a variable instead of 1 and I don't know why

Tags: c#

I'm using C# to code in Unity and I have set different sprites equal to a variable `i`. When `A` is pressed it should add 1 to `i` and when `D` is pressed it should subtract 1, changing the sprite depending on `i`'s value. It was working perfect until yesterday when I just opened it again and now for some reason it will only add and subtract 2 instead of 1. I had changed nothing in the code before it started doing this but I can't figure out why. My code is down below.

```
public void Start()
{
    //Sets i to 4 and spriteRenderer to the current Sprite Rendered.
    i = 4;
    d = 1;
    Score1 = 0;
    spriteRenderer = this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D Death)
{
    //Detects if there is a collision and sets d to 0.
    d = 0;
}

public void Update()
{
    //A bunch of if statements to detect the input key and if the input key is set to GunAngleDown then adds 1 to i or if the input key is set to GunAngleUp the subtracts 1 from i.
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(GunAngleDown))
    {
        i++;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(GunAngleUp))
    {
        i--;
    }

    //If i is equal to 8 then subtracts 1 from i or if i is equal to 0 then adds 1 to i.
    if (i == 8)
    {
        i--;
    }
    else if (i == 0)
    {
        i++;
    }

    //checks the current i value and sets the current sprite rendered to the respective sprite.
    if (i == 1)
    {
        spriteRenderer.sprite = SpriteGunAngleUp3;
    }
    else if (i == 2)
    {
        spriteRenderer.sprite = SpriteGunAngleUp2;
    }
    else if (i == 3)
    {
        spriteRenderer.sprite = SpriteGunAngleUp1;
    }
    else if (i == 4)
    {
        spriteRenderer.sprite = SpriteGunAngleStraight;
    }
    else if (i == 5)
    {
        spriteRenderer.sprite = SpriteGunAngleDown1;
    }
    else if (i == 6)
    {
        spriteRenderer.sprite = SpriteGunAngleDown2;
    }
    else if (i == 7)
    {
        spriteRenderer.sprite = SpriteGunAngleDown3;
    }

    //Checks if d2 is equalt to 0 and sets the rendered sprite to the dead sprite.
    if (d == 0)
    {
        spriteRenderer.sprite = Dead;
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: all that `else if`s you can replace by a `switch` and your code will look a lot  cleaner.

Comment: Is `Update` being called twice, by any chance? I'd add diagnostic logging...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you aren’t in control of exactly when `Update` is called, and it can be called arbitrarily many times while a key happens to be depressed. Instead, you should only count when the key was previously up but now is down - ie. store the current key state at the end of the method, and use it at the beginning of the method to trigger when the key was not down but is now. You’d potentially need to implement key auto-repeat if that’d be desired.

Comment: According to [Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html), `Input.GetKeyDown` only returns true in the frame the key starts being pressed.